# Freepascal procedure parameter of file type default value

Tags: freepascal

A class method has a simple definition

```
PROCEDURE  Print  (str : string = ''; VAR  f : text);
```

This gives the compiler error

```
Error: (3185) Default parameter required for "F"
```

This is strange because on [this page](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu66.html) it says "default values are not supported for variable parameters."  Ignoring that, adding a default value:

```
PROCEDURE  Print  (str : string = ''; VAR  f : text = stderr);
```

gives the compiler error

```
Error: (3203) Illegal expression
```

What is the correct syntax here (by correct I mean how can I make the compiler happy)?

Answer (score 4):

Once a parameter have a default value all the parameters that follow must also have a default, this is why you have

> Error: (3185) Default parameter required for "F"

At this point of the compilation, FPC didn't detect that, grammatically speaking, *F* couldn't have a default parameter, it just see that there is no default.

You declaration should rather be

```
PROCEDURE  Print  (VAR  f : text; str : string = '');
```

---

To go further, let's take this function:

```
procedure foo(a: integer = 8; b: integer);
```

If you call it like this

```
foo(4);
```

The compiler wouldn't know if *4* is for *a* and you forget *b* or if *4* is for *b*. That's why default parameters must always be put at the end. That's also why FPC would emit the following error:

> Error: Default parameter required for "B"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution.  That works.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @Nestedtype explanation.

It can be solved using [overloaded](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu80.html) methods without changes in parameter order like

```
PROCEDURE  Print  (str : string; VAR  f : text); overload; // Calls as Print('foo', f);
PROCEDURE  Print  (VAR  f : text); overload; // Calls as Print(f);
```

and in the implementation section:

```
PROCEDURE  Print  (str : string; VAR  f : text);
begin
    // Do what you need
end;

PROCEDURE  Print  (VAR  f : text);
begin
    Print('', f); // Here '' is the "default" value
end;
```